# Android Collapsing Toolbar remove elevation and shadow

Tags: android, android-layout

I am trying to make a layout that has a gradient into the collapsing app bar which is a solid color. This should be accomplishable through `app:elevation="0dp"` but that has not worked. However, when I run 'Instant Run' on my app, instead of running a full build, I get the desired result. Let me include pictures:

Here is the current look:
**UI with the drop shadow, undesired result**

[image]

Here is the desired look/what appears when I run instant run:
**UI without drop shadow, desired result**

[image]

Here is my layout file:

```xml
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
android:windowActionBar="false"
android:id="@+id/main_background">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/app_bar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="@dimen/app_bar_height"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    android:elevation="0dp"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/toolbar_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed"
        app:toolbarId="@+id/toolbar"
        android:elevation="0dp"
        app:elevation="0dp">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">

        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</recycler>
```

In case this is unclear, I am referring to the drop shadow underneath the app_bar that is labeled "Reee". In the first picture, there is a shadow, in the second picture there is not a shadow. I do not want to have the shadow. However, I can only achieve this look when I run instant run, then it goes away on next run / full compilation.

I'm still looking for a fix for this issues and am quite frustrated that I have not found anything yet. I have tried examples for setting `stateListAnimator=@null` to no avail.

Alright doing some further research, I have a SwipeRefreshLayout with a Recyclerview underneath this appbar. When I remove the RecyclerView, I get the intended affect. What could my RecyclerView be doing, and how can I fix it?

Comment: your question is unclear

Comment: Clean rebuild and invalidate/restart the studio

Comment: Okay, do you see the first picture? That it was it looks like currently. The bottom picture is what I want my app to look. I am using a Collapsing Toolbar Layout with a RecyclerView to show my main content. I believe that I have already set my app_bar not to have a shadow by calling `app:elevation="0dp"` but that has not achieved the desired result.

Comment: @VishvaDave This problem persists throughout restarting and invalidating AS caches.

Comment: try `app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|snap|exitUntilCollapsed"` in collapsing toolbar

Comment: Cannot reproduce the issue. Can you post a simple project with that behavior at github?

Comment: Unfortunately I cannot share the application source itself, but I can provide more needed files such as the activity file and the full layout file if that might help? As well as my stateListAnimator file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I neglected to originally provide the RecyclerView that I have under my AppBar in the question, thinking that the problem was solely the AppBarLayout. But I have since fixed the issue. My RecyclerView looked like this:

```
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginTop="0dp"
    android:background="@drawable/gradient_blue_4"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/transactions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:clipToPadding="false"
        android:fadeScrollbars="true"
        android:overScrollMode="always"
        android:paddingBottom="48dp"
        android:scrollbars="none"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:background="?selectableItemBackground" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Underneath my `AppBarLayout`. Not exactly sure why this fixes the issue, but removing `?selectableItemBackground` as the background for the RecyclerView fixes the issue and leaves me with the desired result.

Thanks to all provided answers, I was originally much more intrigued because I was getting my desired result by running instant run. Unfortunately, this insight provided no additional help.

Answer (score 28):

Just set

```
android:stateListAnimator="@null"
```

or

```
app:elevation="0dp"
```

NOTE: you should use **app:** namespace NOT **android:**

to your AppBarLayout

Comment: app:elevation="0dp" to AppBarLayout worked. 
Thanks

Comment: worked like a charm. should be accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this by setting a custom `stateListAnimator`:

create a new animator "appbar_not_elevated.xml" in `animator` under `res`.

```
<item app:state_collapsible="true" app:state_collapsed="true">
    <objectAnimator android:propertyName="elevation"
                    android:valueTo="0"
                    android:valueType="floatType"
                    android:duration="1"/>
</item>

<item>
    <objectAnimator android:propertyName="elevation"
                    android:valueTo="0"
                    android:valueType="floatType"
                    android:duration="1"/>
</item>
```

This will set the elevation of collapsed as well as expanded state elevation to zero.

Then set the `stateListAnimator` to `AppBarLayout`:

```
android:stateListAnimator="@animator/appbar_not_elevated"
```

Comment: No luck unfortunately, I think this would have worked if I used @null as well, right? For some reason the appbar is still getting a shadow from somewhere.

Comment: Yes? Why else would I say that it did not work? I put up 50 reputation for this answer, of course I tried the suggested solution?

Comment: Once I actually fixed the issue (ie. the recyclerview was causing the problem!), I found that this solution worked to give me the desired outcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

Depending on the support library used, if you read the source code to set app bar elevation, you'll read:

```
/**
 * @deprecated target elevation is now deprecated. AppBarLayout's elevation is now
 * controlled via a {@link android.animation.StateListAnimator}. If a target
 * elevation is set, either by this method or the {@code app:elevation} attribute,
 * a new state list animator is created which uses the given {@code elevation} value.
 *
 * @attr ref android.support.design.R.styleable#AppBarLayout_elevation
 */
```

which tells you, either you use *app:elevation* or a state list animator. For the second option, add an xml selector into the folder *animator-v21*, and then set it to something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item>
    <objectAnimator android:duration="1"
                    android:propertyName="elevation"
                    android:valueTo="0dp"
                    android:valueType="floatType"/>
</item>
```

then refer it from your app bar in xml:

```
android:stateListAnimator="@animator/my_appbar_state_list_animator"
```

Comment: That actually worked the opposite way. It removed the shadow from the collapsed view but kept it for the expanded view, whereas I'm looking for the opposite.

Comment: @schott12521 what I suggest sets (or should set) the app bar elevation to 0 in any state, which I thought is what you want, because the shadow you see is given by the difference in elevation (I assume your items have elevation 0 here). Make sure your created folder has that given name, and make sure you use the one of the latest support library, and it should possibly work. At least it works for me. If it still doesn't work, you can enforce it always to be flat with AppCompat.setEvelation(0) while listening to scrolling, thought I think that's too much at runtime.

Comment: Also CTRL+SHIFT+N and search for _design_appbar_state_list_animator.xml_ you can see the source directly, how the app bar elevation is set in each state. I'm on support 27.0.1 .

Comment: Hmm after it appears that this is almost working as intended, but not perfectly. I verified that the statelistanimator is actually beings selected by setting an elevation of 100dp, and seeing a very large drop shadow. However even with an elevation of 0dp, I still get the unintended effect.

Answer (score 0):

set your AppBarLayout`s  elevation and translationZ to zero

```
appBarLayout.translationZ = 0f
appBarLayout.elevation = 0f
```

Answer (score -3):

In your java file ..

Set A Variable for your app bar and pass in the set id using `findViewById(R.id.whatever`)

and then use

```
void setShadowEnabled (boolean enabled)
```

to disable the shadow.

Hope this helps...

Comment: Are you suggesting I call `findViewById(R.id.app_bar).setShadowEnabled(true)` because I cannot call that method on my appbar, it is unresolved.

Comment: Alright, follow me on this.
Calling `findViewById()` will give me an AppBarLayout!
AppBarLayout does not have a method `setShadowEnabled()`
I cannot call `setShadowEnabled()`